# How far is it from $A$ to $B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the boat moves downstream in the river, then going from country $A$ to country $B$ takes about $4$ hours, whereas if it moves upstream, then the same journey takes about $5$ hours. What is the distance between countries $A$ and $B$ if the river's speed is $2km/h.$

Thanks for your help and your attention.

Comment: I have a task similar to this, only that there is a given distance, and here it is required. Suffice to know the system, then you can solve itself, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $D$ is the distance between the countries, and $x$ is the relative speed of the boat to the water, then $D = 4 (x+2) = 5 (x-2)$ (using standard units of km and hr).  Thus,

$$ {x + 2 \over x - 2} = {5 \over 4} = {20 \over 16}  \implies x = 18$$

Thus, $D = 4\times 20 = 5\times 16 = 80 km$.

Answer (score 0):

Let distance between **A** and **B** be **d**,and speed of boat is $x $ kph.

So,

$\frac{D}{x+2}=4$

and, $\frac{D}{x-2}=5$

$\implies \frac {x+2}{x-2}=\frac{5}{4}$

$\implies 4x+8=5x-10$

$\implies x=18$

So, $d=4\times(18+2)=80 $ km